# I got the error After I installed ryu on my ubuntu

Tags: python, sdn, ryu

I'm trying to install Ryu controller on Ubuntu which I installed on my laptop. I don't understand where my mistake lies

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeo/.local/bin/ryu-manager", line 5, in <module>
    from ryu.cmd.manager import main
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryu/cmd/manager.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ryu.lib import hub
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 30, in <module>
    import eventlet
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('eventlet.green._socket_nodns')
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/green/_socket_nodns.py", line 11, in <module>
    from eventlet import greenio
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from eventlet.greenio.base import *  # noqa
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 32, in <module>
    socket_timeout = eventlet.timeout.wrap_is_timeout(socket.timeout)
  File "/home/jeo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/timeout.py", line 166, in wrap_is_timeout
    base.is_timeout = property(lambda _: True)
TypeError: cannot set 'is_timeout' attribute of immutable type 'TimeoutError'
```

Comment: I've never heard of these libraries, but FWIW I googled the error message and found [this bug](https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/733). At that time the fix wasn't yet released, but there's been a release since then, so maybe try updating. (For reference, I googled `python eventlet "TypeError: cannot set 'is_timeout' attribute of immutable type 'TimeoutError'"`.)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I decided to reinstall everything from scratch. Do you know how to completely remove Ryu from my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to the python version installed in your system. Try downgrading to a lower version between 2.7 and 3.7 if you are using one of the newer ones.